# How to make a custom inspector component

Tags: unity

I have a script component, but I want to know how I can add things like sliders buttons etc.

I wrote a grid system that generates at the start of my script but I want to run it in editor when I push a button to not to force calculations, lessen load times for my game and even see result of my work in editor. How can I do that?

Comment: Hmmm... Sripting

Comment: Check out my profile, I wrote a course that includes it, use the free trial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you need.

For instance if you need to display a slider in the inspector you need to declare your slider

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

[Range(0, 100)]
public Slider sldr;
```

to Add a buttom you could follow [this simple tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/editor/adding-buttons-to-inspector).

**EDIT**:

As per your edit and Byte32 suggestion would be usefull to you to check also for this [basic Custom Editor tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/editor/building-custom-inspector?playlist=17090).

Comment: @virtouso Yeah, it would do, with a slightly different tutorial: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/editor/building-custom-inspector?playlist=17090

Comment: @virtuoso I based my answer on what I caught at first glance in your question. I updated it with suggestions.